# ¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo aquí? "Remedios decidió que fuera considerado..."

Tags: subjuntivo

De *Cien años de soledad:*

> Cuando nació el hijo de Aureliano y Pilar Ternera y fue llevado a la
>   casa y bautizado en ceremonia íntima con el nombre de Aureliano José,
>   Remedios decidió que **fuera** considerado como su hijo mayor.

No entiendo como puede usar el subjuntivo con "decidir"...

Mi intento: Quizá quiere decir que decidió que ***se* fuera** considerado asi, es decir que ella lo siente e inluirá o mandará a los otros lo mismo.

---

Para el registro: la buena respuesta de ukemi llegó al mismo segundo que mi conjetura se editó así ninguno repetía el otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Acordar/decidir + indicativo:** Pensar de común acuerdo (think)

> Patricia d̲e̲c̲i̲d̲i̲ó̲ que estudiar **era** lo mejor que podía hacer.

**Acordar/decidir + subjuntivo:** resolver de común acuerdo (decide)

> Hemos d̲e̲c̲i̲d̲i̲d̲o̲ que te **vayas** unos días de vacaciones.

---

**Fuentes:**

<sup>• https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=36507</sup>
 <sup>• https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pensar-decidir-subjuntivo.1592271/</sup>
 <sup>• http://www.timandangela.org.uk/spanish/58-el-subjuntivo-verbos-de-doble-significado</sup>
 <sup>• https://blogs.transparent.com/spanish/spanish-lesson-advanced-4-verbos-con-doble-significado-segun-se-usen-con-indicativo-o-con-subjuntivo/</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*Respuesta suplementaria, para que lo entiendas más intuitivamente.*

Vamos a pasar la frase al presente:

> Remedios decide que sea considerado como su hijo mayor.

Observa esta parte:

> Que sea considerado como su hijo mayor.

Ahora se puede reconocer más fácilmente como una estructura común de subjuntivo, como por ejemplo *¡Qué viva México!* o *¡Que se vaya al diablo!*